# How to apply camera tracking datapoints in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have used [Autodesk's MatchMover](https://apps.autodesk.com/MAYA/en/Detail/Index?id=appstore.exchange.autodesk.com%3Aautodeskmatchmover_windows64%3Aen) to camera track a video. What would be the appropriate way to apply those data points to cameras in Three.js?

My goal:
I want to use three.js to create a hovering object 'inside' a video, therefore I need to know the camera movement inside the video.

Comment: I +1'd your question as it is a very interesting topic. 

However, three.js is a *rendering* library, which is orthogonal to the tracking functionality you are after. One you have the tracking information, all you do in three.js is *set* the position and orientation of the camera. Point being: three.js is rather irrelevant to the question. 

Also, is your video pre-recorded or live camera footage? If it is pre-recorded, you'll definitely want to extract the camera track beforehand (offline), which might also mean you don't have to use javascript to do it.

Comment: Thanks @Paul-Jan, I indeed have a pre-recorded movie. Am I correct in stating: I am looking for a way to auto-generate WebGL compatible camera positions like MatchMover?

Comment: Yes, although I fear the question will be too broad. A specific question would be: "I extracted several data points from my movie using Voodoo. They look lik [this], how do I apply these to the three.js camera?". (Voodoo is at http://www.viscoda.com/index.php/en/products/non-commercial/voodoo-camera-tracker).

Comment: Thanks, updated the question